# Как передать инпут с типом file в Битрикс24 через batch?

Tags: php, битрикс24

Есть произвольная форма:

```
<form id="form_to_crm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file_diagnoz" name="FILE_DIAGNOZ">
</form>
```

Передаю:

```
$sFileDiagnoz = $_FILES["FILE_DIAGNOZ"];

require_once('crest.php');
$result = CRest::call('batch',
    array(
        'halt' => false,
        'cmd'=> array("user_deal"=> 'crm.deal.add?fields[UF_CRM_1681835277381]='.$sFileDiagnoz //Убрал лишние поля для читабельности
)
```

Сделка создается, но файл не передается. Что я упустил? Как передать файл в Б24 в пользовательское поле с таким же типом file? Нужно ли его декодировать в другой формат?